# Insert statement with a join between two tables

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to be able to insert data from two tables inner joined to a third table with a trigger, my insert query is the following:

```
INSERT INTO reg04_rpt_animreg 
(animalid
,tagid
,tagprefix
,tagsec
,name
,color
,sex
,inadggbundle
,hh_id
,regdate) VALUES 
(NEW.animalid
,NEW.tagid
,NEW.tagprefix
,NEW.tagsec
,NEW.name
,NEW.color
,NEW.sex
,1
,NEW.farmermobile
,now()
);
```

But I need to inner join two table to get the value of `NEW.farmermobile`, is it possible to do in an inner join with an insert statement?

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you saying NEW.farmermobile is in a different table to all the other NEW. values?

Comment: `INSERT INTO x... SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values to insert from a `SELECT` query rather than a literal `VALUES` list.

```
INSERT INTO reg04_rpt_animreg (animalid, tagid, tagprefix,tagsec,name,color,sex,inadggbundle,hh_id,regdate)
SELECT NEW.animalid, new.tagid, ,NEW.tagprefix,NEW.tagsec,NEW.name,NEW.color,NEW.sex,1,
        t1.column, now()
FROM someTable AS t1
JOIN someOtherTable AS t2 ON t1.something = t2.somethingelse
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bad practice because it means duplication of your data.
It's better to just insert the data into the two tables and then, when you need the data to be joined, use a `SELECT` query with an `INNER JOIN` to get the data from the 2 tables into 1 result table.

You could also define a VIEW that does this for you. However, don't duplicate your data. It makes things complicated.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). See [why do I need 50 reputation to comment, what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) for an explanation.